# Auctex & Ghostscript config

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

I have a problem with my Auctex + Emacs in LateX Preview functions.
They are located in my USB together TexLive packages, Sumatra pdf-reader & all Ghostscript tools.

1. Where can I include Ghostscript path to allow the Latex preview functions go on in correct way?
   (I mean what variable must include the Ghostscrip bin path and others binary file used in windows i.e. Ghostxps & Ghostpcl).
2. What is the binary "rungs.exe" included in TeXlive that is called by preview-gs-command variable?
   (If I see the variable I find "f:/Program-folders/TeXlive2015/bin/win32/rungs.exe").
3. What can I do to remove into Emacs exec-path others files 
   that the installation program read from windows path variable and they are not used in usb pen drive?